# excess elements in scalar initializer c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, compiler-errors

As in the question at "[Excess elements of scalar initializer for pointer to array of ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108416/excess-elements-of-scalar-initializer-for-pointer-to-array-of-ints)", I too am working on Ex. 5–9 in K&R, trying to convert

```
static char daytab[2][13] = {
    {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
    {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
};
```

into

```
static char *daytab[] = {
    {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
    {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
};
```

and am getting the errors described there. However, the accepted answer of

```
static char arr[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
static char (*ptr)[3] = NULL;

ptr = arr;
```

just gives me another error at `ptr = arr` of

```
error: data definition has no type or storage class
```

Can anyone help?

Also, why is it legal to use an array of pointers to `char` arrays, such as

```
static char *name[] = {
    "Illegal month",
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September",
    "October", "Novemer", "December"
};
```

but not `int` arrays?

Comment: See updated answer. I enhanced answer for your second question a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your code looks like (as error message by `gcc` is exactly the same):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char arr[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
static char (*ptr)[3] = NULL;
ptr = arr;

int main(void)
{       
    printf("%d\n", ptr[0][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

This is indeed invalid, as `ptr = arr;` assignment is placed outside of any function. The syntax rules of C language allow only to place it inside, like here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    static char arr[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
    static char (*ptr)[3] = NULL;
    ptr = arr;

    printf("%d\n", ptr[0][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

There is also fundamental difference in meaning of `static` keyword for both those examples. The former affects *linkage*, and the latter *storage duration* of particular object, that is represented by identifier.

For your second question, you may simplify it into more basic form:

> Why the following is legal:
>
> ```
> char *name = "January";
> ```
>
> while this is not:
>
> ```
> int *name = "January";
> ```
>
> ?

Here (as well as in previous form in your question), `"January"` is interpreted not as array initializer, but as *string literal*.

These literals are read-only (any attempt to modify them results into [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) objects of type `char[n]`, where is n equal to number of characters between `"` delimiters (with special handling of *escape sequences*), plus one for *null character* (represented in common as `'\0'`). The value of `n` is always known in compile-time for string literals. They have *static storage duration*, so you can think of them like existing objects, that are already present, when the is program is being executed.

The pointer to `int` is incompatible with `char[n]` array, so you cannot assign string literal to `int *`.

To be honest, yes you can "force" it, by explicit cast, like here:

```
int *name = (int *) "January";
```

but any attempt to read from such pointer would violate [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), that results into UB.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, for the second part, I was more wondering why `char *name = "January";` is legal, but `char *num = {1, 2, 3};` is not? Is the string literal treated as an existing array?

Comment: Ah, that is what I was wondering, that the string literal is treated as a pre-existing array. Thanks again!

Comment: char * name = "January"; is being converted by the compiler to char * name[8] = {'J','a','n','u','a','r','y','/0'}; Where [ char ] the compile add a /0 to the end of the array.