# C - char array and char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings, string-literals

Why I can't define
an array

```
char **pp={ "123", "456", "789" };
```

But I can define it as a char*[] ,and send it to a function that will accept it as a char **

```
char *pp[]={ "123", "456", "789" };
fun(pp);

void fun(char **pointerToPointer)
{
    //++(**pointerToPointer);//error
    printf("%s", *pointerToPointer); 
}
//output::"123"
```

And why I can't increment

```
++(**pointerToPointer);
```

Comment: I can define `char **pp={ "123", "456", "789" };` .. What compiler are we talking about?

Comment: What is the purpose of using `++(**pointerToPointer)` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. , With warnings though...

Comment: "_And why I can't increment `++(**pointerToPointer);`_" Because the strings you have are string literals and they are immutable.

Comment: I am working with VS 2013. the purpose of using ++(**pointerToPointer); is that printf("%s", *pointerToPointer);  will print "223"

Comment: @ZagGol , If you want to modify the string, use `char pp[][100]={ "123", "456", "789" };`. Replace the 100 with the maximum length of a string-1. Also change `void fun(char **pointerToPointer)` to `void fun(char (*pointerToPointer)[100])`

Comment: The next question should be why this declaration is good: `char *p = "abc";`

Comment: @CoolGuy I am not getting the reason behind the increment. Please tell me more about it

Comment: Hm. It's actually interesting why `char *p = "ab";` is not the same as `char *p = {'a', 'b', '\0'};`

Comment: @Subinoy , Increment if you want to change the first character of the string. For example, `"123"` will give `"223"` when the first character is incremented.

Comment: @CoolGuy are you getting the `"223"` output. Mine is making runtime error

Comment: @Subinoy , Because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532077/c-char-array-and-char-pointer/30532586?noredirect=1#comment49138180_30532077). Fix it by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532077/c-char-array-and-char-pointer/30532586?noredirect=1#comment49138449_30532077)

Comment: @CoolGuy you mean "replace the 100 with the maximum length of a string +1"

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first question, the principles might be clearer if we use a single depth of pointer. This code is illegal for the same reason:

```
int *ptr = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

In C, a braced initializer list is not an object (especially not an array). It can only be taken as a list of items from which to read initializers when an object is being initialized.

`ptr` is one object, so at most one initializer could be taken, and the expected form of that initializer is a pointer (which `1` is not).

In fact this code is explicitly illegal under C11 6.7.9/11:

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces

However, there is a gcc bug/feature where it permits excess initializers for a scalar and ignores them. Further, some compilers may "be helpful" and "only" issue a warning, and initialize `ptr` to point to address `1`, wherever that might be.

"scalar" means an object that's not a struct or an array.

---

Since C99 you can write:

```
int *ptr = (int []){1, 2, 3};
```

which creates an array (using the same storage duration as `ptr`) and points `ptr` at its first element.

This array is mutable; for a non-mutable one use `int const *ptr = (int const[]){1, 2, 3};` instead.

---

Replacing `int` by `char *`, we see that you could write:

```
char **p = (char *[]){ "123", "456", "789" };
```

in which case *the pointers in the array* are mutable, but the things they point to (i.e. the string literals) still aren't.

Note that you should always use `char const *` when dealing with string literals, because they are not mutable.  The fact that string literals have type `char [N]` is a historical hangover from before `const` was added to C. So:

```
char const **pp = (char const *[]){ "123", "456", "789" };
```

or with non-mutable pointers to strings:

```
char const *const *pp = (char const *const []){ "123", "456", "789" };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `char *pp[]={ "123", "456", "789" };` is correct because:

- Here it is an array of pointers which can be used to point to an array of data items with each element of the pointer array pointing to an element of the data array.
- As we assign  each array to a `char` pointer, it works fine.

But in case of `char **pp={ "123", "456", "789" };`

- Here the memory initialization is not happening.
- Instead of this first string is assigned to the pointer and then compiler generates warning saying other many values are discarded.

As **CoolGuy** said `++(**pointerToPointer)` it is error because it accessing `1` of `"123"` string, and trying to change the value of `1` to `2`, and as these are string literals assigning can't be done. You can only see the increment value of print: 
`printf("%c\n", **pointerToPointer+1);`
which will give output : `2`

You can solve it by the solution provided by **CoolGuy** in the comment-

1. By changing `char *pp[]={ "123", "456", "789" };` to `char pp[][100]={ "123", "456", "789" };`
2. By changing `void fun(char **pointerToPointer)` to `void fun(char (*pointerToPointer)[100])`

It is correct because here the value of `**pointerToPointer` is getting changed.

These are the reasons to me. And for the warning:

`warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]`

you can see the link in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108416/excess-elements-of-scalar-initializer-for-pointer-to-array-of-ints) which is the best explanation of it to me.

Comment: one array means? @CoolGuy Please edit it if you see any mistakes

Comment: `char *pp[]={ "123", "456", "789" };` declares an array of pointers, each of type `char*`. Actually, 4 arrays can be seen here ( I was wrong ), Each string literal is an array as well.

Comment: Yeah it get out of my, I have edited it. I just forget the concept. Sorry for mistakes @CoolGuy

Comment: Isn't there are three arrays?@CoolGuy

Comment: Four. Three strings `"123"`,`"456"`,`"789"` and `pp`.

Comment: Oh yeah you are correct @CoolGuy, But the three stirngs are `123`, `456` and `789`, that's what I am trying to say to you. Am I right?

Comment: but why I could get it in the function  as char ** ?

Comment: Here it is just taking the first string and trying to assign it to `char**`, for this reason it it not happening @ZagGol