# What is the difference between these two definitions?

Tags: c

What is the difference between these two definitions?

```
char *string = "MyString";
char string[] = "MyString";
```

As much as I know, the first one is a pointer to a string.

Comment: C does not have a string type. And the answer can be found by learning the language basics.

Comment: Their type and the number of indirections a compiler creates to access the object.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533439/string-literals-vs-array-of-char-when-initializing-a-pointer

Comment: [What is the difference between char s`[]` and char *s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The first is a pointer to a string literal, the second is an array initialized with the contents of the string literal (*which BTW when optimized points exactly to where `string` points*).

The first one lives in the read only segment of the program's memory and thus cannot be modified.

The second one is an array of 9 elements and you can modify any of the 9 elements including the termnating `null` byte that is not explicitly set in the code in your question.