# C - Difference between [] and *

Tags: c, gcc

What is the difference between these two declarations ?

```
char *format = "sss jj mmm aaaa hh:mm::ss\n";
char format[] = "sss jj mmm aaaa hh:mm::ss\n";
```

In fact, the difference I saw is that with the * declaration I can't use strncopy with format as destination ( bus error ), but with the [] declaration I can use strncopy without problems.

What can explain this behavior ?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1704407/612920

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533439/string-literals-vs-array-of-char-when-initializing-a-pointer)

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha