# Why a string declared between quotation marks seems to be sometimes mutable, sometimes immutable?

Tags: c, string, pointers, gcc, mutable

I know that when declaring `char * s = "arbacadabra";`, `"abracadabra"` refers to a `const char *`, but I cannot understand why when declaring `t[] = "abracadabra"`, `"abracadabra"` is not interpreted as a `const char*` anymore, as long as it seems to be mutable.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
        char * s = "abracadabra";
        char t[] = "abracadabra";
        //s[0] = 'x';//produces an error
        t[0] = 'x';
    }
```

Comment: `"abracadabra"` is not mutable in either case.  In `t` you are allocating a new array and copying the characters from `"abracadabra"` into this array

Comment: Thus, "abracadabra" is another way to write {'a','b','r','a','c','a','d','a','b','r','a',NULL}, in the "t" case?

Comment: not really, as that syntax would not be accepted on the `s` line .  It is an array of chars if that is what you are trying to say .

Comment: @pauk Yes in the 't' case (not NULL but `'\0'`)

Comment: This is to your question in the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533439/string-literals-vs-array-of-char-when-initializing-a-pointer

Comment: My bad, it was '\0'. Also, why the compiler does not warn me somehow when I try to access and modify s[0]. I encounter a segmentation fault signal only after compiling the code.

Comment: Some systems allow writing via the `s` method and some don't.  The former are not very common these days but the language was designed a long time ago .  You can add `-Wwrite-strings` to your compile flags in gcc to get a diagnostic for this

Comment: Because it is not syntactically incorrect. But does invoke undefined behavior. C is very permissive. In a sense that it will let you shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Indeed, but here the tricky thing is that a pointer to a constant should not let one change the value contained by it, as long as it is constant. It is something similar to attributing a new value to a macro.

Comment: @pauk You have never told the compiler this pointer is to something constant. How can it know? What if you reassign it with something "mutable"?

Comment: `char * s = "abracadabra";` should be `const char * s = "abracadabra";`  then the compiler will not allow *writing* to `s[N]`, but will allow *reading* from `s[N]`.

Comment: Then, why I didn't get any compile error (or not even a warning) when performing char*s="abracadabra" without cast?

Comment: P.S.: I use CLion

Comment: Because the type of string literal is `char[]` and not `const char[]`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-and-c